# Issue with using React-Bootstrap-Typehead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I'm building a typehead using react-bootstrap-typehead and running into a TypeError.

**Details:**
I can successfully type into the field, filter options, and use the menu, however, upon selecting an option the page goes blank and shows this error:

*"TypeError: Cannot read property 'onChangeState' of undefined"*

```
  160 | <Typeahead
  161 |   id="basic-typeahead-example"
  162 |   labelKey="state"
> 163 |   onChange={(e) => this.onChangeState(e)}
      | ^  164 |   options={[
  165 |     { state: 'AL' },
  166 |     { state: 'AK' },
```

**Typehead:**

```
function StateInput() {

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

  return (
    <>
      <Typeahead
        id="basic-typeahead-example"
        labelKey="state"
        onChange={(e) => this.onChangeState(e)}
        options={[
          { state: 'AL' },
          { state: 'AK' },
          { state: 'AZ' },
          { state: 'AR' },
          { state: 'CA' }
        ]}
        placeholder="Choose a state..."
        selected={selected}
        value={setSelected}
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

**onChange function:**

```
  onChangeState(e) {
    this.setState({
      state: e.target.value
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues as far as I can tell.

1. I'm not sure where you're defining `onChangeState` with respect to `StateInput`, but the error is happening because `this` isn't bound correctly and is therefore undefined. If the method is coming from the parent component, you should pass it in as a prop (`props.onChangeState`).
2. The argument passed to `onChange` by the typeahead is actually [an array of selections](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/blob/master/docs/API.md#typeahead), not an event.
3. React Bootstrap Typeahead doesn't accept a `value` prop, so `setSelected` isn't doing anything there.

The following should work:

```
const StateInput = (props) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

  return (
    <Typeahead
      id="basic-typeahead-example"
      labelKey="state"
      onChange={setSelected}
      options={[
        { state: 'AL' },
        { state: 'AK' },
        { state: 'AZ' },
        { state: 'AR' },
        { state: 'CA' }
      ]}
      placeholder="Choose a state..."
      selected={selected}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found your post because I was trying to implement fetching data onChange, with the value as a query to fetch data (options, in Typeahead). And for this case **AsyncTypeahead** worked better for my case, where `onSearch` has the same behaviour as your typical `onChange`.

See more here: http://ericgio.github.io/react-bootstrap-typeahead/#asynchronous-searching